# comparar dos objetos y unir propiedades diferentes en Javascript

Tags: javascript, objeto

Tengo obj1 y obj2 definidos de la siguiente manera:

```
var obj1 = {
  coche: 1,
  hijos: 2,
};
var obj2 = {
  hijos: 4,
  mascotas: 3,
};
```

Necesito crear una función que meta las propiedades del obj2 en el obj1 sin sobreescribir los valores que ya se hayan dado en el obj1. El resultado debería quedar así:

```
obj1={
coche: 1,
hijos: 2, //misma propiedad, NO se sobreescribe
mascotas: 3
}
```

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (let [llave1, valor1] of Object.entries(obj1)) {
    for (let [llave2, valor2] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
      if (llave2 !== llave1) {
        obj1[llave2] = valor2;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(obj1);
}
```

Esto me devuelve un obj1 incorrecto porque me está sobrescribiendo la propiedad hijos dando un resultado de:

```
    obj1 = {
coche:1,
hijos: 4,
mascotas:3 
}
```

Ayuda por favor!!!

Comment: what language is it?

Comment: it is javascript, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejo esta otra opcion que resuelve tu problematica tambien. Una ventaja es que no se usan dos `for` para validar si alguna propiedad del objeto dos existe en el objeto 1.

```js
const obj1 = {
  coche: 1,
  hijos: 2,
};

const obj2 = {
  hijos: 4,
  mascotas: 3,
};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  const keysObj1 = Object.keys(obj1)
  const keysObj2 = Object.keys(obj2)

  for (let key of keysObj2) {
    if (!keysObj1.includes(key)) {
      obj1[key] = obj2[key]
    }
  }
}

extend(obj1, obj2)

console.log(obj1)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo!! Buscaba algo así!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto seria lo más simple para conseguir tu propósito:

```js
var obj1 = {
  coche: 1,
  hijos: 2,
};
var obj2 = {
  hijos: 4,
  mascotas: 3,
};


function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (let [llave, valor] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
    if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(llave)) {
      obj1[llave] = valor;
    }
  }
  console.log(obj1);
}

extend(obj1,obj2);
```

La diferencia con tu código está en que *no hace falta recorrer ambos objectos* y comparar **todas** sus claves.

Recorremos solo el segundo objeto, y comprobamos si el primero tiene la propiedad mediante la función `hasOwnProperty()` y si no la tiene la agregamos. En caso contrario **no hacemos nada**.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega otro If.
//Aquí evaluas, si hay otro key igual (en el objeto 2), de ser así, mantienes en valor1 en el objeto uno.

```
....
    if (llave2 == llave1) {
             obj1[llave2] = valor1;
    }
.....
```

Funcioncompleta

```js
var obj1 = {
  coche: 1,
  hijos: 2,
};
var obj2 = {
  hijos: 4,
  mascotas: 3,
};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
  for (let [llave1, valor1] of Object.entries(obj1)) { 
    for (let [llave2, valor2] of Object.entries(obj2)) { 
      if (llave2 !== llave1) { 
        obj1[llave2] = valor2;
      }
      if (llave2 == llave1) {
          console.log(llave2+'>>:'+llave1);
        obj1[llave2] = valor1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(obj1);
} 
extend(obj1,obj2);
```

Comment: perfecto!! También funciona!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente, con un poco menos de código, basicamente es unir dos objetos, uniendo el segundo al primero sin afectar las claves de este ultimo:

```js
let obj1 = {coche: 1, hijos: 2},
    obj2 = {hijos: 4, mascotas: 3},
    mergeObjects = (firtsObj, secondObj) => {
  Object.keys(secondObj).forEach(key => {
    if (!firtsObj[key]) firtsObj[key] = secondObj[key]
  })
  return firtsObj
}

let res = mergeObjects(obj1, obj2)
console.log(res)
```